# How to stop propagation of Gesture.Tap()?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

Here is a minimal example of how I tried to set up two nested `GestureDetector` with `Gesture.Tap()` gestures.

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {Gesture, GestureDetector} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function PropagationTest() {
  const outerTap = Gesture.Tap()
    .onBegin(() => {
      console.log('onBegin outerTap');
    })
    .onStart(() => {
      console.log('onStart outerTap');
    })
    .onEnd(() => {
      console.log('onEnd outerTap');
    })
    .onFinalize(() => {
      console.log('onFinalize outerTap');
    })
    .maxDuration(99999);

  const innerTap = Gesture.Tap()
    .onBegin(() => {
      console.log('onBegin innerTap');
    })
    .onStart(() => {
      console.log('onStart innerTap');
    })
    .onEnd(() => {
      console.log('onEnd innerTap');
    })
    .onFinalize(() => {
      console.log('onFinalize innerTap');
    })
    .maxDuration(99999);
  
  return (
    <GestureDetector gesture={outerTap}>
      <View style={styles.outerView}>
        <GestureDetector gesture={innerTap}>
          <View style={styles.innerView} />
        </GestureDetector>
      </View>
    </GestureDetector>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  outerView: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  innerView: {width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'blue'},
});
```

[image]

When I tap the red box, I get this console output:

```
### My finger goes down ###
onBegin outerTap

### My finger goes up ###
onStart outerTap
onEnd outerTap
onFinalize outerTap
```

When I tap the blue box, I get this console output:

```
### My finger goes down ###
onBegin innerTap
onBegin outerTap

### My finger goes up ###
onFinalize outerTap
onStart innerTap
onEnd innerTap
onFinalize innerTap
```

## Why is "onStart" not called on both Gestures as soon as I touch down my finger?

I want to play a scale animation on the red box only if I press on the red box and revert it when the press is released again.

## How can I achieve that the Gesture is not propagated?

Right, in some sense it already doesn't get propagated, because if I press and release on the blue box, the outer "onStart" is never called.
But if someone has an answer to my first question and it gets called, the "onStart" should not propagate through.

Answer (score 0):

Try *composing gestures*.

For example:

```
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {Gesture, GestureDetector} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import style from './style';

export default class ExternalComposing extends React.Component {
  private tapA = Gesture.Tap().onStart(e => {
    console.log('panA');
  });

  private tapB = Gesture.Tap()
    .onStart(e => {
      console.log('panB');
    })
    .simultaneousWithExternalGesture(this.tapA);

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <View style={style.container}>
        <GestureDetector gesture={this.tapA}>
          <Animated.View style={style.boxA}>
            <GestureDetector gesture={this.tapB}>
              <Animated.View style={style.boxB}></Animated.View>
            </GestureDetector>
          </Animated.View>
        </GestureDetector>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and `style.js`:

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  boxA: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    zIndex: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },

  boxB: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    zIndex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
});
```

This worked for me.

You can explore this in depth in [swmansion.com's *React Native Gesture Handler* documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/gesture-composition#composition-vs-simultaneouswithexternalgesture-and-requireexternalgesturetofail).